# cPanel displays other PHP version than PHPmyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, cpanel, php-7

in my hosters' cPanel I have set PHP to version 7.2 for my WordPress site. When I go into PHPmyAdmin Webserver is displayed as being at version 5.6.30.

Why that discrepancy?

Newbie is grateful for any hint, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The WHM / cPanel server that your cPanel account is hosted on can have multiple PHP versions installed so that outdated applications can also be hosted on it.

> in my hosters' cPanel I have set PHP to version 7.2 for my WordPress site

- Your hosting provider offers PHP 7.2 so that your own applications can use that version. If older PHP versions are installed they're also available for use, PHP 5.6 is installed by default.

> When I go into PHPmyAdmin Webserver is displayed as being at version 5.6.30.

- phpMyAdmin is an application that provides a web interface for you to interact with the databases hosted in your cPanel account. It's built on PHP and requires it to run. The default PHP version that WHM/cPanel servers use for their own services is PHP 5.6. This is why it's displayed in your phpMyAdmin's interface.

Your WordPress' PHP version and the PHP version that your phpMyAdmin use can be different. One PHP version is used for all PHP services on the server (phpMyAdmin is the only one that comes by default) and the other is used to serve your WordPress installation's content.